# Dual boot with a x86 OS and a x64 OS

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I have a PC with Windows 7 x64 pre-installed on it. 
I want to install Windows 7 x86, but I don't want to do it over the current one or to loose my Recovery Partition.
So I figured that I'll use Windows' Disk Management utility to shrink the current partition (apart from the Recovery and the OEM partition there is only one of about 900 GB) and install the x86 OS on the new partition. 
Do I need to do something before this to ensure that the OSes will get along well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these OS run on different partitions, there is **no issue** when it comes for dual-booting with two **OS** with different architecture standards.

The only possible issue is when you are trying to install a **x64 OS** on a **32-Bit** computer. Thiss WILL lead to issues.

**< sidenote >**

Why do you need to install a *x86* version of the OS? Is this for debugging? If so, I would recomend that you use a VirtualBox rather than dual-booting if it is only for testing purposes, not for mainstream use
**< sidenote >**

Comment: I knew something about the x64 after x86 issue and I was wondering if something similar can happen in my case. It is for debugging, but I want to also test things out on a real computer, not just on a VM. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @user3804799 :)